# Any point in checking origin of window.parent with postMessage?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, same-origin-policy, postmessage

I have a script meant to be included by third party sites that creates an iframe (on our origin). Something like this:

```
// this script exists on the *host site*
const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = "https://us.com/iframe";
parent.appendChild(iframe);
```

The script exposes an API which internally communicates with the iframe through `postMessage`, something like:

```
// This script exists on the *host site*
function getSomeProperty()
{
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject)
    {
        theIFrame.postMessage("getSomeProperty", "us.com")
        window.addEventListener("message", function (event)
        {
            // ... get the response, making sure its from us.com, etc.
            // This is just pseudo code, we don't create a new listener
            // on every call in our real code.
            resolve(answer);
        }
    });
}
```

All this is fine, my question is with regard to the iframe's corresponding "message" listener. Specifically, I want to *only* respect requests from the creating window/origin. In other words, if some parallel iframe on a separate origin (say, an ad) constructs a `postMessage` to us, we want to of course ignore this. My question is whether it is *sufficient* to simply check whether the sending `window` is `window.parent`:

```
const parent = window.parent;

// This event handler is in the *embedded iframe*
window.addEventListener("message", function (event)
{
    // This is being sent from a window other than 
    // the one that created us, bail!
    if (event.window !== parent)
         return;

    // it is safe to respond...
}
```

As far as I understand it, the only way that this would *not* be a sufficient check is if it was possible for window.parent to *change origins* while simultaneously keeping us around. I can imagine scenarios where an iframe could be removed from one host and appendChild'ed onto another host, but I believe this could only happen if the DOM manipulator was on the same origin (and thus have access to said DOM) and placing us into another window of the same origin too.

Currently, we employ an extra paranoid defense of passing the original origin to the iframe through the query string as such:

```
const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.src = `https://us.com/iframe?location=${window.location.href}`;
```

Thus allowing us to check that `window === window.parent` AND that `origin === originalOrigin`. However, we'd really like to move away from this model since it necessarily breaks caching across different sites (as each one generates a different src URL due to the different query string). So, is it safe for us to move to solely checking `window === window.parent`?

Answer (score 0):

When using the `postMessage` API, the only truly safe way to ensure messages are coming from where they say is to use a strict `targetOrigin`. This way you can ensure that messages are coming from a window you control.

You're right in saying that this condition would prevent incoming messages other than from the window that created them. However, an iFrame with `src="https://us.com/iframe";` could still be created on *any origin*. What if it was created on a malicious page? This would still satisfy the condition such that `window.parent === parent` is `true`.